# Why is my onClick button not calling the function inside EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently serving a `/frontend.js` file inside my public folder inside an express application. I have then added this to the head tag of my EJS file inside `<script>` tags. As seen below:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wow Leaderboards - 2v2 US</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/medstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
    <script src="/frontend.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

I then add a button to my EJS file which im using to call an alert function inside the `/frontend.js` file.

**Button inside .ejs file**

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

**function inside  `frontend.js`**

```
function myfunction(){
  alert('hello')
}

myfunction()
```

The function works inside the EJS file when the page loads if i call it inside of the `frontend.js` file but it does nothing when I try to call it using the onClick method. I have noidea why this is not working. Anyhelp is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the output of the console or just copy past it into your question.

Comment: There is no output inside the console? The button does nothing when clicked?

Comment: JavaScript variable names are **case sensitive**. `myFunction()` won't call the function you defined because it is called `myfunction`. Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo.

Comment: Do not confuse JavaScript running in an HTML document that is generated from EJS (i.e. a `<script>`) with JavaScript running in EJS (e.g. with `<%`)

Comment: Ive changed the typo and it still doesnt work

Comment: *Warning* intrinsic event attributes such as `onclick` have a host of problems, including really weird scoping rules. They are not recommended. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener) instead.

Comment: @Zeronir — If the script runs when the page loads, and the typo doesn't exist, then the only explanation I can think of is that some code you haven't shown is overwriting or shadowing the function.

Comment: @Quentin Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-attr 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

Comment: this is in my console when i click the button

Comment: Well, that's a pretty clear error message. What problem are you having dealing with it?

Comment: I have noidea what it means @Quentin

Comment: Try typing "Content Security Policy" into Google.

Comment: @Quentin I'll give it a read. But how why would adding a button effect security?

Comment: It wouldn't. You've added an inline script. XSS attacks generally insert inline scripts. The security policy is set to assume that a legitimate developer isn't going to use an inline script (using something sensible instead) and thus blocks them.

Comment: when you say inline script. Do you mean inside my package.json file or my <script> tags?

Comment: @Quentin so is the solution to add an event listener in my script to handle the onclick event?

Comment: @Quentin Event listener worked. Thank you for your help